# Ajax responseText and echo broken, returning header file contents

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, echo

I have the following code in my thePhpFile.php file to handle an Ajax call:

```
<?php
    require_once('usefulStuff.php'); // stuff used throughout the code 

if (isset($_GET['zer']))
{

   $bFound = false;


  if(! $bFound)
  {
     echo "notfound";
     return;
  }   
  else 
  {
      echo "found";
      return;
  }
}
?>
```

Here's the inline onreadystate function (javascript) that handles the responseText:

```
var theResponseText = "rText";
var zer = "testing";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        theResponseText = xmlhttp.responseText;
        alert("responseText is >>>" + theResponseText + "<<< that.");

        if( theResponseText == 'notfound')
        {
            alert("sorry, nothing found.")
        }
    }
}

var ajaxText = "thePhpFile.php?zer=" + zer;
xmlhttp.open("GET", ajaxText, false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

If I add, say, newlines or anything else, really, in my usefulStuff.php include file -- and I add it at the bottom of usefulStuff.php, **after** the **?>** closing tag -- the following line of code from above, an echo statement, goes out of its way to locate and grab those extra newlines, etc. and return them in my responseText:

```
 echo "notfound";
```

Having written a compiler, and dealt with BNF grammars, I don't get why the echo statement in php was set up to 'echo' anything more than what immediately follows the 'echo' up to the first semicolon ';' that is encountered during the parse.

I know I can use trim() to undo the whitespace, but my question is, I want to compel my echo statements above to behave in the manner the echo syntax above suggest it *should* act.  If there is a good reason why the echo statements above are going around looking for extraneous whitespace in my include files to return with my "notfound" text, I don't know what reason that would be, but I want to disable that unexpected behavior.

I want my line of code  **echo "notfound";** to do that and nothing more -- simply to echo the word **notfound** and to stop echo-ing when the semicolon is encountered immediately after the "notfound" text.

How can I limit the **echo** behavior to only echo what immediately follows the word **echo** and stops the echo-ing when the semicolon is reached?

By the way, while experimenting with my usefulStuff.php file's contents that fall outside of the **?>** termination tag, I added this at the end of that file:

```
 // now ending the php code in usefuleStuff.php:
?>
<noscript>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; 
         URL=http://mywebsite.com/noscript.html"/>
</noscript>
```

The line of code  **echo "notfound";** -- when I retrieve my responseText -- the response text contains all three **noscript** lines of code also, plus any extra whitespace, in addition to my "notfound".

So the 'echo' in php is garbage-collecting whatever I put at the end of my included usefulStuff.php file.

How can I limit echo's behavior to do what the line of code **echo "notfound";** leads you to to believe it would do, that is, echo only the word "notfound" ?

Comment: common,just crop your question..just post the relevant part of your doubts

Comment: What happens when you remove the echo statement and run it again?

Comment: I see exactly what you 2 guys said I might, the contents of my include'd usefulStuff.php file that is at the end of the file outside the closing ?> tag -- even with no echo statement, my responseText still contains data, the stuff outside that closing ?> tag in my include file -- thanks man, I was not aware how that could happen, and I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled on a solution to my question, which was *how can I make the statement **echo "notfound";** in an Ajax call do exactly what the syntax seems to suggest* -- I appreciate the explanation of 'why' I'm getting extra stuff that the simple line of code **echo "notfound";** does not upon first glance suggest would happen.

Here is how I forced the syntax of  **echo "notfound**;** to do what it looks like it should do, which is to send the word **notfound** as my responseText and nothing else -- I stumbled across this from a highly-peripherally related post that only mentioned the php function 'ob_end_clean()' and I took it from there.

Here's my modified code that returns a tightly-controlled chunk of data as my Ajax **responseText**:

```
<?php
require_once('usefulStuff.php'); // stuff used throughout the code 

if (isset($_GET['zer']))
{
   $bFound = false;


   if(! $bFound)
   {
      ob_end_clean();
      ob_start();
      echo "notfound";
      ob_end_flush();
      return;
   }   
   else 
   {
      echo "found";
      return;
   }
}
?>
```

To verify this works, I put ten newlines, and the following code, at the very end of my usefulStuff.php file, outside of the closing **?>** tag:

```
   // now ending the php code in usefulStuff.php:
   ?>

    // ten newlines here....

   <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; 
              URL=http://mywebsite.com/noscript.html"/>
   </noscript>
```

And now, regardless of any code or whitespace outside of my closing **?>** php tag in my usefulStuff.php include file -- my responseText in my Ajax onreadystatechange function contains exactly what I expect it to be, "notfound", and *nothing else.*

I have not used output-buffering functions since my C programming days in the 1980s and early-1990s.    This is my first experience using php's output buffering functions, but it really allowed me to finely control what my responseText looks like in my Ajax call.